# Need to reset whole postgres database, want to backup a table in the database

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I give up. Migrations are effed up. encountering error after error. I'm so sick and tired of this right now.

I just want to move on. So I guess it better to wipe all data because of one table is messed up.

Is it possible to backup ONE table, not a database, before wiping? And then after import this back to that table?

I use postgres db.

Comment: [dumpdata](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/django-admin/#dumpdata) lets you dump your data to json and specify which apps and which models.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use Django dump data for a single model

it will export json file from app or single model then you can get it back by load data

[Django dump data doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/django-admin/#dumpdata)